# Xcode эмулятор iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, swift

При запуске приложений в `Xcode`, на любом из предложенных эмуляторов видно только 10-20% экрана. И вверх никак нельзя прокрутить. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: если есть возможность добавить картинку, чтобы было нагляднее, то, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Окно -> Масштаб поставь 50-75% если у тебя не ретина экран.

Answer (score 1):

[image: масштаб симулятора xcode]
Нужно изменить масштаб как показано на скрине

Answer (score 0):

Изменение масштаба эмулятора через хот кей cmd+1+2+3+4